# How can I read file from react project in my npm package?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a npm package，

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mypackage",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "keywords": [
    "wowgo-object-to-css-in-js"
  ],
  "author": "taiwanhua",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/taiwanhua/wowgo-object-to-css-in-js/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/taiwanhua/wowgo-object-to-css-in-js#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-in-js-utils": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

and **main.js**

```js
import {config} from 'from the react project that use this package s path'  /// i want read the config from react project

export const consoleConfig = () => {
    console.log(config)
}
```

then I have react project use "mypackage",
the tree of react project:

- |- config
- |-- config.js
- |- src
- |-- App.js
- |-- index.js
- |-- ...other file

**config.js** :

```js
export const config = "i want to pass to mypackage"
```

I want to read the config "i want to pass to mypackage" in my npm package.
How can I do that?

I have tried many times,but it is not working.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. Take a look at this solution. By this way, you can read any file from npm packages.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417764/how-to-reference-local-files-in-a-npm-module

Comment: Just now, I have read the webpage you provided, but that is not what I want.
I need read config.js from react project,and then i want to use config.js in my npm package.